# Is it possible to return an item in a list, for use in another method?

Tags: c#, list, methods, parameters

Working with Unity.

Sorry if this seems ridiculous, or if the answer is obvious.

I have a foreach loop which cycles through some items in a list, but only certain objects are subject to a set of further instructions:

(randomValues is an int array which stores seven random numbers, every item in the list has an ID.)

```
foreach (var item in itemsList)
{
    if(randomValues.Contains(item.itemID))
    { 
        //Code not relevant.         
    }    
}
```

I want to take whatever items are worked with and use them in another method. So I thought about passing the item out as a parameter for the method, but then realized I have no idea how I'd do that, and I don't know if such a thing is even possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do (or if Unity is relevant at all).  Are you trying to pass in the list to this method or pass `item` to another method?

Comment: Replace `//Code not relevant` with `othermethod(item)`

Comment: Try using *Linq*: something like `itemsList.Where(item => randomValues.Contains(item.itemID))`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that may not be applicable if there's a large amount of logic within the loop and if you call it in addition to the foreach loop, you'll be iterating twice.

Comment: You're following the right thought process--by returning a subset of your values you increase the modularity of your code. By having your method create a new object and return that, instead of modifying a global collection, you make your method a pure method, which is a wonderful thing.

Comment: @DStanley I'm trying to pass in item to another method.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how your objects/methods are structured.  Do you need to pass a single item to a method?

```
foreach (var item in itemsList)
    if (randomValues.Contains(item.itemID))
        SomeOtherMethod(item);
```

Do you need this current method to filter the list to only the ones which should be later passed to another method?

```
foreach (var item in itemsList)
    if (randomValues.Contains(item.itemID))
        yield return item;
```

Do you need to pass a list of matching items from within this method to another method?

```
var matchingItems = new List<SomeType>();
foreach (var item in itemsList)
    if (randomValues.Contains(item.itemID))
        matchingItems.Add(item);
SomeOtherMethod(matchingItems);
```

Or even just use LINQ:

```
SomeOtherMethod(itemsList.Where(i => randomValues.Contains(i.itemID)));
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
var tempList=new List<int>();//assuming int values in list    
foreach (var item in itemsList)
{
    if(randomValues.Contains(item.itemID))
    {
        tempList.Add(item); //add item to temp list
        //some code
    }
}
return tempList;
```

Answer (score 0):

`var itemsCopy = itemsList.Where(i => randomValues.Contains(i.itemID)).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
return itemList.where (item => randomValues.Contains(item.itemID));
```

I selected not to use ToList() to benefit from a lazy evaluation.